# How to consume objects with different avro namespaces from one Kafka topic with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, deserialization, avro

I have to consume a kafka topic, which contains objects with different avro namespaces. Unfortunately, I can't change the content of the incoming topic, and I have to consume the data.
As the deserializer I'm using the `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer`.
This is my kotlin code which consumes the records:

```
@Incoming("some-ingest")
    fun consumeMyTopic(records: ConsumerRecords<String, Any>) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled) {
            logger.debugf("some-ingest: consuming %d record(s)", records.count())
        }
        var recordsDogs = records.filter { k -> k.value() is Dog }.map {
            it as ConsumerRecord<String, Dog>
        }
            .map { toDog(it, DogMapper::convertToEntity) }

        val recordsCats = records.filter { k -> k.value() is Cat }.map {
            it as ConsumerRecord<String, Cat>
        }
            .map { toProgramme(it, CatMapper::convertToEntity) }

        dogService.saveDogs(recordsDogs)
        catService.saveCats(recordsCats)

    }
```

This way, the casting doesn't work. I get empty lists for `recordsDogs` and `recordsCats`.
I've tried different Deserializers like the `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer`, but that also didn't work.
I assume I have to write a custom Deserializer that maps different namespaces to different objects. But maybe there is another way. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!